# Find the horizontal distance between two node of binary tree considering empty nodes also?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, tree, time-complexity

I have binary tree where each node holds unique integer. I want to find the horizontal distance between two nodes lying on the same level.
It may possible some nodes does not have child nodes or child sub-tree, but to calculate distance we need to considered those empty nodes also. Like in attached binary tree Distance(7, 1)=3 and Distance(9, 4)=6. 
For that I have tried the following steps:

1. Converted a existing tree to full binary tree. Added empty nodes to the nodes where child sub tree or node not present to meet full binary tree criteria.
2. Traverse the tree with Breadth First Search algorithm and stored the traversal in dictionary as level wise.
3. Take user input values such as level, first_node, second_node and after all validation of nodes in tree gives the distance between them.

By following above steps I get the solution but it takes **O(N^2)** of time complexity. To make Binary tree to full binary tree takes **O(N^2)** as well as to traverse using BFS takes **O(N^2**) time complexity.

Is there any other approach to solve this problem so that traversing need to be done only not full binary tree conversion process?

My code implementation

```py
from pprint import pprint
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.right = None
        self.left = None

    @property
    def maxDepth(self):  # get the height of tree
        depth = 0
        if self.left:  depth = self.left.maxDepth + 1
        if self.right: depth = max(depth, self.left.maxDepth + 1)
        return depth

    def expandToDepth(self, depth=None):  # full binary tree conversion method
        if depth is None: depth = self.maxDepth
        if not depth: return
        if not self.left:  self.left = Node(None)
        if not self.right: self.right = Node(None)
        self.left.expandToDepth(depth - 1)
        self.right.expandToDepth(depth - 1)


d = {}


def traverse_dfs(root):  # traverse the whole tree with BFS algo
    h = root.maxDepth + 1
    for i in range(1, h + 1):
        level_traverse(root, i, i)


def level_traverse(root, level, original_level):  # traverse the nodes at particular level
    if root is None:
        return
    if level == 1:
        if d.get(original_level):
            d[original_level].append(root.data)
        else:
            d[original_level] = [root.data]
    elif level > 1:
        level_traverse(root.left, level - 1, original_level)
        level_traverse(root.right, level - 1, original_level)


root = Node(5)
root.left = Node(2)
root.right = Node(3)
root.left.left = Node(7)
root.left.left.left = Node(9)
root.right.right = Node(1)
root.right.right.right = Node(6)
root.right.right.left = Node(4)

root.expandToDepth()  # convert normal tree to full binary tree

traverse_dfs(root)    # BFS traversal and stor the level wise traversal in dictionary d.

pprint(d)

level = int(input("Enter level: "))
first_node, second_node = map(int, input("Enter two nodes separated with space: ").split())

print("Getting horizontal distance between given nodes lies on the same level")
if first_node is None or second_node is None:
    print("None type nodes are invalid")
    exit()
if d.get(level):
    if first_node in d[level] and second_node in d[level]:
        distance = abs(d[level].index(first_node) - d[level].index(second_node))
        print(distance)
    else:
        print("Distance invalid")
else:
    print("Invalid level")
```

Output:

```py
{1: [5],
 2: [2, 3],
 3: [7, None, None, 1],
 4: [9, None, None, None, None, None, 4, 6]}
Enter level: 3
Enter two nodes separated with space: 7 1
Getting horizontal distance between given nodes lies on the same level
3
```

[image: Binary tree]

Comment: How is the input in actual cases? Do you get the instance of the root node? Or are you responsible for creating the Node instances from a more basic, string input?

Comment: No. Only root instance will provided. which can be changed to full binary tree.

Comment: Tree is same as provided in image. Thats the input. Create same and then user input will be provided like level and nodes.

Comment: And the two nodes are given by their values, not by their Node instance, right? Why does the input need to provide the level? You would need to verify they are on the same level anyway, so why ask?

Comment: Yes. As provided in output snippet.

Comment: level is just to check on which level distance need to calculate. Ok and level is secondary entity in this. even if it is not provided then elements need to verify on each level while iterating.

Comment: Level signifies only to get all those elements of particular level in tree.

Comment: And we may assume of course that values are unique in the tree.

Comment: Yes. Values are unique integers in tree.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213561/discussion-between-akash-pagar-and-trincot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, adding the missing nodes is inefficient. You can derive this distance without those. Imagine the lowest common ancestor of the two chosen nodes, and how the paths to the two nodes from there give a clue about the nodes that *could* be there.

For example, for the input 9 and 4, the common ancestor is the root. The path from the root to the first node is LLL (left-left-left). The other path is RRL.

Now lets play with the first path. Imagine it was LLR instead of LLL: that would make the distance shorter by 1. Or imagine it was LRL instead of LLL: that would make the distance shorter by 2. In fact, you would notice that such unitary path changes, have an effect to the distance that is a power of 2. The power is how far away upwards you are from the node.

So, ... you could create those paths as binary numbers. In the example: 000 and 110.
Now subtract those from each other as binary representations: you get 6. That is indeed the distance.

So your code could be:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

def dfs(root, d={}, path=""):
    if root:
        d[root.data] = path
        dfs(root.left, d, path+"0")
        dfs(root.right, d, path+"1")
    return d

root = Node(5)
root.left = Node(2)
root.right = Node(3)
root.left.left = Node(7)
root.left.left.left = Node(9)
root.right.right = Node(1)
root.right.right.right = Node(6)
root.right.right.left = Node(4)

# create a dictionary of <nodevalue, path>
d = dfs(root)

val1, val2 = map(int, input("Enter two nodes separated with space: ").split())

# convert the numbers to the corresponding paths:
node1 = d.get(val1, None)
node2 = d.get(val2, None)

# check whether these nodes actually exist
if node1 is None or node2 is None:
    print("At least one value is invalid or not found")
    exit()

# If the paths have different lengths, the nodes are not on the same level
if len(node1) != len(node2):
    print("Nodes are not on the same level")
    exit()

# Use the magic of binary numbers:
dist = abs(int(node1, 2) - int(node2, 2))
print(dist)
```

Comment: that is really shortest way to solve this. is it a Huffman coding approach? @trincot

Comment: There is indeed some similarity with how Huffman coding works.